# Is there a way to hide the collapse/expand button in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I'd like to align the titles in my swimlanes to the left side, but the collapse/expand buttons are hiding the words. Is there a way I can make that kind of button invisible?

I've looked through the code that's editable and haven't found it there either. When I use element inspector it shows the collapse/expand button as being separate from the container it's attached to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the swimlane and on the menu invoke Arrange->Collapsible

[image]

To toggle the collapse/expand button.

Comment: Just as a note, I had to click on Collapsible twice to get the toggle buttons to disappear. Other than that this worked like a charm, thank you @David.